# Determine Winner from Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to determine a winner depending on information inside the table. The structure looks something like this:

`Match:
match_id | team_ a | team_b | score_a | score_b`

Now I need to create a Select Statement/View that provides the winning team, so if score_b > score_a it should display team_b and otherwise team_a.

Any pointers to how I might be able to create a Select statement like that are greatly appreciated! Also, sorry for the bad title, I truly don't know how to better describe it.

UPDATE:
For the Sample

```
match_id | team_ a | team_b | score_a | score_b
1        | foo     | bar    | 2       | 1
```

I would want the query to return something along the lines of

```
match_id | winner
1        | foo
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  a case when

```
select case when score_a > score_b then team_a 
            when score_a < score_b then team_b 
            else '===='
        end  winner 
from my_table
```

Comment: Oh, thank you kindly! I only worked with Oracle up to now and never knew this syntax existed! Should do exactly what I need.

Comment: case when  ..end  .. is common in SQL

Comment: Well, to be fair I am only studying and just because our Prof never told us about it doesn't mean it isn't far spread.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray If you like computer science you will soon learn that what you study at school is only a small part of what is available from languages, libreries and algorithms

Answer (score 1):

If a tie can't occur, it'd be something like that:

```sql
SELECT
    match_id,
    CASE WHEN score_a > score_b 
        THEN team_a
        ELSE team_b
    END as Winner
FROM Match
```